# Best way to deal with multiples projects when using go mod/vendors

Tags: packages, go

I am pretty new with go mod and vendor... I have a project A and a project B out of the GOPATH. I import project A in project B.

I own both projects and I modify them. As I use externals packages from GitHub, I want to use go mod so I wont be impacted by any breaking changes.

Problems come when I want to modify project A and use modifications in project B. As I use vendor, I will need to push my code and merge it in my default branch to be able to use it in project B. It seems to be pretty heavy, I would like to modify both projects at the same time and then merging them (is it a good practice ? Idk)

The other solution I found is to modify the vendor to check if modifications are working, and then C/C in the main directory. But I don't even want to try this one.

What is a good way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just needed to add the line replace in the go.mod with my project A (And I moved my project in the GOPATH again)